# Create a vertical button bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, kendo-ui, responsive-design

I have created a vertical button that sticks to the right side of screen but the issue is that the button is not response is there a way to make the button responsive. Im using bootstrap 3
Here is a sample code for the buttons.

**HTML**

**Edit**

I have a [kendo scheduler](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/angular) I'm trying to align the buttons to the right side of this [kendo scheduler](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/angular)

```
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="margin-left: -1%;">
    <div kendo-tooltip k-content="vm.theContent" k-filter="'.k-event'" class="k-group" style="background:white;border-top: 2px solid #b1b1b1;">
      <div id="scheduler" kendo-scheduler="vm.scheduler" k-options="vm.schedulerOptions" k-rebind="vm.schedulerOptions">
         <!--something--->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="col-lg-offset-11 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 vertical-bar" >
   <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm vertical-btns">
     <i class="fa fa-angle-double-up" style="font-size:24px;"></i>
    </button><br>

    <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm vertical-btns">
     <i class="fa fa- angle-double-down" style="font-size:24px;" ></i> 
    </button> 
</div>
```

**css**

```
.vertical-bar{
  top: 36.6%;
}

.vertical-btns{
  padding: 11px 10px    !important;
  line-height: 17.6em   !important;
}
```

Comment: To what should it respond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bootstrap class of btn-group-vertical like this:

```
 <div class="btn-group-vertical">
      <div class="col-lg-offset-11 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 vertical-bar" >
    <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
     <i class="fa fa-angle-double-up" style="font-size:24px;"></i>
    </button><br>

    <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
     <i class="fa fa- angle-double-down" style="font-size:24px;" ></i> 
    </button> 
</div>
    </div>
```